# Calculating the total number of elements in a matrix written in a file

Tags: c, file, matrix

i have a file with a matrix of integers NxN , how can i allocate the correct memory for a matrix in my program with the proper dimensions.

```
    int i, j;
FILE *file_ptr;
file_ptr= fopen( "matrice.txt" , "r");
if(file_ptr==NULL) {
    printf("errore nome programma");
    return 1;
}

int N;
fseek(file_ptr, 0L, SEEK_END); 

N = (ftell(file_ptr))/16;   
fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
if( N < 4){
    printf("matrice di dimensioni inferiore a 4");
    return 1;
}

int **file_matrix = (int**)calloc( N , sizeof(file_matrix));
for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i ++){
    file_matrix[i]= (int*) calloc( N , sizeof(file_matrix));
    }

for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){

    for(j = 0 ; j < N ; j++){
        if(!fscanf(file_ptr , "%d" , &file_matrix[i][j])) break;

    }
```

The problem i got is that if i write a 7x7 matrix, it is properly printed, if i change it and i write a 4x4 , it prints much more elements that are zeros because i allocated with a calloc. 
Better: without if( n < 4) it prints zeros ; with  it , program printes the error wrote in the if

```
1 0 4 0 4
2 3 4 9 4
1 3 4 5 4
0 0 1 0 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Why is N the size of the file divided by 16?  Shouldn't it be `isqrt(ftell / sizeof(int))`?

Comment: Instead of seeking, why didn't you store the matrix' size in the first line of the file? Are you allowed to format the file in a better way then reading all values in a sequence?

Comment: no, im asked to calculate the dimension unluckly. I tried sqrt((ftell(file_ptr))/sizeof(int)) but it returns me N=1; @TomKuschel my file is formatted as a matrix , not as a sequence of integers

Comment: @xing i edited my post, adding an example

Comment: I _think_ that it's a mistake to try to wrap up the entire calculation in one expression. Confirm that the result is a multiple of `sizeof(int)` first, then divide it by that to get the number of integers. Then confirm that that is a square number. You should bail out if either isn't true.

Comment: sorry, its new for me. @TomKuschel

Comment: Calculating the size of the matrix from the file is only possible if you have a binary file which consists of integer sized values, each integer follows the next one. If you want to use this line with  `if(!fscanf(file_ptr , "%d" , &file_matrix[i][j])) break;`, I suppose you try to read-in ascii integer values, which differ in length, and also contains spaces between each value, so the length of the file doesn't make any sense.

Comment: so are you saying that if i have a file with a matrix NxN wrote like in the post, and i have to calculate its size , i just cant? @TomKuschel

Comment: @xing but i wont know the dimension of the matrix

Comment: if you have always NxN matrix, you could read-in up to the end of the first line, only parsing the amount of integers, then you get the count N. Afterwards you can handle the allocation of memory and read-in the whole file.

Comment: @TomKuschel could u write an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find value of `N` only reading first line:

```
int N = 0;
char* line = NULL;
ssize_t read, len;

if ((read = getline(&line, &len, file_ptr)) != -1) {
    char *n = strtok(line, " ");
    do { 
        N++;
    } while ((n = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL);
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
}
fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Because of `ftell` function only returns the file length in bytes, it cannot be used to take the number of integers, since in your ASCII file numbers are separated by space `" "`.
So after retrieved first file line you can tokenize it with `strtok` separating with space token and take number of integers in it:

```
char *n = strtok(line, " ");
do { 
    N++;
} while ((n = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL);
```

Also remember to `#include <string.h>` for `strtok` function.

Pay attention also of `calloc` sizes:

```
int **file_matrix = (int**)calloc( N , sizeof(file_matrix));
file_matrix[i] = (int*) calloc( N , sizeof(file_matrix));
```

should be

```
int **file_matrix = (int**) calloc( N , sizeof(int*));
file_matrix[i] = (int*) calloc( N , sizeof(int));
```

Comment: you may/should release the line buffer afterwards with `free(line);
  line = NULL;` - btw thanks for coding.

Comment: getline is aviable only on posix right? tho thank you very much

Comment: According to `man` page of `getline`:

> Both `getline()` and `getdelim()` were originally GNU extensions. They were standardized in POSIX.1-2008.